# show which package repo was used to obtain a package

Tags: evil, package, package-repositories, doom

I'm trying to submit a bug report to emacs-evil, and they ask me from which repo evil was installed.

I'm just using the version that came bundled with doom-emacs.

How can I know which source was used to install a mode? is that information saved with the mode in emacs? must I look at the source of the doom config to find where it downloads files?

Comment: If it's the xclip thing, DONT. It has nothing to do with evil.